# Assign conditional type based on a different variable type

Tags: typescript

```
function handleAddFilter(
    mode: 'PaymentType' | 'Origin' | 'Destination',
    value: string,
  ) {

  }
```

I want to change this function so that if `mode` is `'Origin' | 'Destination'`, then value should be of type `string`. If mode is `PaymentType`, value should be of type `'Payment in' | 'Payment out'`

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads?

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wj857m) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is looks like case for function overloading.

```
function handleAddFilter(
    mode: 'Destination' | 'Origin',
    value: string,
  )
function handleAddFilter(
    mode: 'PaymentType',
    value:'Payment in' | 'Payment out',
  )
```

Some teorii
https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/function-overloading

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the two function argument into one object-type argument, and then create two separate types for your two separate use cases.

```
type I1 = {
  mode: 'Origin' | 'Destination';
  value: string;
};

type I2 = {
  mode: 'PaymentType';
  value: 'Payment in' | 'Payment out';
};

function handleAddFilter(args: I1 | I2) {}

handleAddFilter({
  mode: 'Destination',
  value: 'asdf123',
});

handleAddFilter({
  mode: 'PaymentType',
  value: 'Payment in', // You get full type completion
});
```